# Cakephp, Select top 5 results then group the rest to "Other"?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

How do i view the top 5 results and group the rest under "Other" in **Cakephp 2**? If i have a table "visits" with the field "page", it has for example 100(it will be alot more) rows and i need results to be like:

```
Other    40
/        20
/about   15
/contact 10
/welcome 10
/test     5
```

This is one way to do it with regular Mysql:

```
    SELECT case when v2.page is not null then v1.page else 'other' end AS viewpage, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM visits v1
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT page, COUNT(*) as pcount
        FROM  visits
        GROUP BY page
        ORDER BY pcount DESC
        LIMIT 5
    ) v2 on v1.page = v2.page
    GROUP BY viewpage
    ORDER BY count DESC
```

But how to do this in **Cakephp 2**? Thought it would be easy when i had the Mysql query made up...

Answer (score 0):

If performance isn't an issue (and it shouldn't be if you're only dealing with 100 rows), it's probably going to better to just fetch all results and then loop through and calculate totals using PHP.

Before anyone pipes up about "php shouldn't do it if the database query can", compare the two solutions in your head, and admit that a php solution would probably be:

- less lines of code
- easier & quicker to write & maintain
- easier for others (or your future self) to understand

Yes, it'll take a split second longer to run, but no one will notice that.

Comment: Okey, the 100rows was just an example to show that i needed all rows to be presented. This table will be to big to query all the results from.